# Implementing multi-tab browser powerpoint plugin in c#, disappears on second visit

Tags: c#, plugins, webbrowser-control, powerpoint

I am trying to implement a multitab webbrowser plugin in powerpoint using c#.

So far, i am using shdocvw.webbrowser objets over  multitab and set the visibility of them to true or false based on the corresponding tab. It works alright.

The problem starts when I want to view the multitab slide for the second time while slideshow. By some untold reason, my webbrowser objects disappear except for the first one! I tried to set the zorder or visibilty but none of them worked! Interestingly, the browsing seems to be done since the tab title changes as the web page title does!

My Code is like this:

```
                PowerPoint.Shape tabStrip = sld.Shapes["tabs"];

                PowerPoint.Shape webShape1 = sld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(left, top + 60, width, height * (float)0.85 - 60, "Shell.Explorer.2");
                PowerPoint.Shape webShape2 = sld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(left, top + 60, width, height * (float)0.85 - 60, "Shell.Explorer.2");
                PowerPoint.Shape webShape3 = sld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(left, top + 60, width, height * (float)0.85 - 60, "Shell.Explorer.2");
                PowerPoint.Shape webShape4 = sld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(left, top + 60, width, height * (float)0.85 - 60, "Shell.Explorer.2");
                PowerPoint.Shape webShape5 = sld.Shapes.AddOLEObject(left, top + 60, width, height * (float)0.85 - 60, "Shell.Explorer.2");    

                tabStrip.ZOrder(Office.MsoZOrderCmd.msoSendToBack);

                webShape1.Name = "web1";
                webShape2.Name = "web2";
                webShape3.Name = "web3";
                webShape4.Name = "web4";
                webShape5.Name = "web5";

                SHDocVw.WebBrowser web1 = webShape1.OLEFormat.Object;
                SHDocVw.WebBrowser web2 = webShape2.OLEFormat.Object;
                SHDocVw.WebBrowser web3 = webShape3.OLEFormat.Object;
                SHDocVw.WebBrowser web4 = webShape4.OLEFormat.Object;
                SHDocVw.WebBrowser web5 = webShape5.OLEFormat.Object;


                webShape1.OLEFormat.Object.Visible = true;
                webShape2.OLEFormat.Object.Visible = false;
                webShape3.OLEFormat.Object.Visible = false;
                webShape4.OLEFormat.Object.Visible = false;
                webShape5.OLEFormat.Object.Visible = false;

            web1.Navigate2(webAdress[currentSlide, 0]);
```

I create 5 shapes containing the webbrowser object every time the slide is visited in SlideShow Mode and delete the webShapes when the user visits the other slides, then make the first one visible and the rest invisible. It works fine at the first run but

Please help me what should I do?

Comment: You need to show your code; otherwise, it's all guesswork

Comment: You're right! I've updated the post with my code.